# How to support all languages (fonts) on Ubuntu minimal

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, apt

By default, the docker `ubuntu` image or other minimal ubuntu are support English only. But there are some features like text to image or PDF generation that depends system fonts that corresponding to the content.

For now, the `fc-list` is:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf: DejaVu Serif:style=Book
```

It caused some Non-ASCII character display as a square. There is a case: https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/non-ascii-characters-display-as-square-characters-in-confluence-317948797.html

So, I want a best practice to support all languages on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 related solution:

1. Install Google Noto Font. (https://www.google.com/get/noto/)

> But it's so large about 1.1GB. I didn't try it.

2. Install all language-pack:

```
apt install -y language-selector-common
check-language-support -a | xargs apt install -y
```

It solved my problem, but I'm not sure this is the best practice.